# GIT: update to specific revision

Tags: git

I checked out a project copy 8 months ago, made lots of changes there. 
Now, I'd like to take all the new changes for the last 8 months. The amount of changes is overwhelming (tens of thousands of commits). What I'd like to do is to take changes of 1 month at a time, merge with my version, test. If I pull latest the amount of changes/conflicts is overwhelming.

So... I guess it's clear what I'm trying to do, but I have no clue how to do it with GIT (I'm more familiar with svn). I use TortoiseGit on windows. All my local changes I committed to local branch, what do i need to do to pull changes made since I checked out, but not all of them?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `pull` is just a combination of a `fetch` plus a `merge`.  So do a `fetch` to get all the remote changes down to your local repo, then `git log master..origin/master` to get a list of all the commits made on `origin` since your branch diverged, then pick any SHA1 about a month up and `git merge SHA1` to pull it into your `master` branch.  Lather, rinse, repeat.

If there are fewer changes on your side, it might be easier to do a `git checkout -b upstream origin/master`, `git log upstream..master`, and merge *your* changes over a month at a time.

I don't know if splitting it up is going to end up being less work in the long run, though.  If you merge it all in one chunk, you're not really merging 10,000 commits, you're merging the *tips* of the branches, which means all those commits essentially get squashed into one big one.

Comment: +1 for `I don't know if splitting it up is going to end up being less work`

Comment: I agree about extra work, but when I rebase to latest I get overwhelmed with amount of conflicts and I simply loose track of where of where I am and have to restart eventually from scratch. Doing it gradually is not that painful :) I'm see tomorrow if I got it all right

Comment: I didn't understand half of what you wrote. I don't use git at all and I don't use git command line at all at all ;) It's the project that I need to merge changes from uses git. I checked it out once 8 months ago and never used git since then. My goal is to get my changes on top of latest code, but I can't simply rebase because of insane amount of conflicts, only looking at the list of changes made me quit. In short, that git merge SHA1 does not work because when I tried to merge second month of changes I had the same conflicts once again.

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  When you did the first merge, did you add and commit all the files after fixing the conflicts?  Which SHA1s are you using, yours or theirs?  What branch is checked out when you do the merge?

Comment: yes, when I use check for modifications in TortoiseGIT and I select shown unversioned files I saw no changes. I resolved all conflicts, added new files and committed all the changes to my repository. Then I went to log of changes and tried to merge second month and I see all the same conflicts and when I try to resolve them I see that the base version is the same ancient base file. Do I need to rebase or something to the SHA1 that I used when merging? (SHA1 was obviously of the 1st or 2nd month revisions)

Comment: to clarify. There was a file folder/file.c 8 months ago. I modified it and when I tried to merge 1 month of changes I resolved conflicts to that file. When I merge to the second month I get conflicts because I already have most the changes made to that file. The conflicts are in short because we have the same changes. When I checked changes in that folder/file.c, I see that all the changes between 1st and 2nd month are trivial and the absolutely had to be merged without conflicts, but because it uses ancient base file as a base tortoise git shows me conflicts once again.

Comment: that thing with merges is missing something or is plainly wrong, I even get conflicts in files that I never changed!

Comment: What branches are you using to do this?  Just `master` and `origin/master`?

Comment: I really have no idea what it means at all!

Answer (score 2):

You can always just merge up a couple commits at a time. Just look back and say month 1 is 345bbdkj...., `git merge 345bbdkj` (just enough of the hash to identify the commit). You can keep on doing that until you get a conflict.

Additionally, you can rebase your repo so your changes are made on top of all these other changes instead of the other way around. Your changes will become a mess no matter what you do here I think though :( 10k+ commits is a lot to deal with.

Comment: Does not work with that repetitive merge strategy. I merged first month of updates, merged all conflicts. Now when I tried to merge second month of the changes I see the same conflicts once again.